# Citation of Books vs. Patents using verbose style

Tags: biblatex

I am currently working on my bachelors thesis and I am using the `biblatex` package for my citations and so on. Below a minimal example. The book and the patent have all minimal fields filled (author, year, title, number...). When I cite the book, everything looks fine in the bibliography as well as in the footnote:

> Autor, Title, Year.

When I cite the patent, LaTeX makes it look like the following:

> Author, "Title", Year.

I don't want those " around the title. Any idea of how to get rid of those?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose,citestyle=authortitle-ibid]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Literatur.bib}

\begin{document}
Book\autocite{ArensFischer.2000}\\
Patent\autocite{AnandSrinivasanMartinL.WilliJoelD.HiltnerMinWu.1999}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `style=verbose,citestyle=authortitle-ibid` should actually be the same as `style=authortitle-ibid`.

Answer (score 3):

The formatting is set in the file `biblatex.def` with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
```

To overwrite this for patents, you can put

```
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [patent]
  {title}{#1\isdot}
```

into your local `biblatex.cfg` or your preamble.

For more general information about customizing your BibLaTeX style you might want  to take a look at [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles).